# iOS Custom Emoticons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There are apps in the app store that allow you to use custom emoticons (smileys, etc.). My question is: Is is possible to take a picture on the phone, then crop it, scale it down, and set it as one of the emoticons on the keyboard?

Comment: Of course it is. You have to get access to Photos folder. Then resize the image, and figure out the code for setting the keyboard key that image.

Comment: …“and figure out the code for setting the keyboard key that image”? Of course it’s possible to make your phone fly you into space—you just have to find the code to make the rocket engines come out.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon thats a good quote. Do you mind if I use it from time to time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no. You can certainly take a picture from the camera roll and crop it to emoticon size, but there’s no way to attach it to the keyboard, short of making an entirely custom keyboard which would only be accessible inside your own app.

Comment: On this "Custom" keyboard, would it allow me to put the emoticon in a line of text as the standard ones work? Or would it send it as a picture via SMS. I would want it to work like thus "This is my text message [emoticon image here] and here is some more text"

Comment: Neither, unfortunately. Emoji in SMS messages works because both devices have their own set of resources to display the emoticon characters—there’s no actual image data being transferred.

Comment: So there is no way to send custom emoticon image (made in app) via SMS ?

Comment: Only via a third-party gateway; `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn’t let you supply anything but text as a message body. Even then, the image probably would not show up inline; most phones display MMS images separately from the text surrounding them.